# newcerts directory filename

Tags: ssl, openssl

We are using a root CA and 2 intermediate CAs that's been deployed in 2 different servers. Using the intermediate CAs, we are generating server and client certificates.

One thing I noticed is that, there is a newcerts folder and each time I create a cert, a new file is being generated in the /newcerts directory with file names 1000.pem, 1001.pem, etc.

Can I make this file name unique? For certificate revocation I need users to be identified uniquely from both this intermediate CA's.

Comment: Nam(es like 1000.pem, 1001.pem sound unique to me, i.e. each name is different. Apart from that: [openssl ca](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/ca.html) is just a *"sample minimal CA application"* so don't expect to much fancy features from it.

Comment: How are you running `openssl ca`? You would usually be able to call both `openssl req` and `openssl ca` with the option `out` where you can specify the output file name. The serial number method will be used if you instead specify an output directory but no filename.

Comment: Problem that you have same certificate names on both servers? E.g. you have 1000.pem and 1001.pem on both servers? And you want to have odd certificate names on first server and even names on second server. Right?

Answer (score 1):

The **newcerts** subdirectory for a CA is the "new_certs_dir" parameter in the  openssl config file (`/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` on many linux dists).
[Here's the OpenSSL source code tree.](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/openssl.cnf)

The file name itself (the 1000.pem, 2000pem, etc in your question) is specified with the `-out` parameter when creating the certificate.